# AsyncTask, RejectedExecutionException and Task Limit

Tags: android, error-handling, android-asynctask

I am fetching lots of thumbnails from a remote server and displaying them in a grid view, using AsyncTask. The problem is, my grid view displays 20 thumbnails at a time, so that creates 20 AsyncTasks and starts 20 executes, one per thumbnail.

I get `RejectedExecution` exception in my code. I recall reading somewhere that there is a limit to number of tasks that AsyncTask can have in its queue at a time, i might be hitting that. Was this bar lifted?

Is there a way to increase this limit? Is it safe to just ignore this exception?(by having an empty `catch(RejectedException e){}` block?)

I am running this code on Android 1.6 emulator and the API level in my code(minSDKVersion is 3). 
[EDIT: Added SDK and API level info]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I recall reading somewhere that there
>   is a limit to number of tasks that
>   AsyncTask can have in its queue at a
>   time, i might be hitting that. Was
>   this bar lifted?

`AsyncTask` appears to presently support 10 threads and a work queue depth of 10. In theory, that would just support 20 items...if nothing else is using `AsyncTask`.

> Is there a way to increase this limit?

Grab the source code, modify it, put it in your own package, and use that one. I did this with my [`AsyncTaskEx`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-task), though that is based on the Android 1.5 source.

> Is it safe to just ignore this
>   exception?

Your work will not be queued for execution. Whether that is "safe" is up to you. I am not aware of any other impacts on the `AsyncTask` infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply and also for sharing your code!  
BTW, as per Romain Guy's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990948/simple-thread-management-java-android the limit seems to have been relaxed.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't confirm his statement. What I have above is from my examination of the source code (as found via Google Code Search). It could be I am misreading the code, though.

Comment: I'm hitting the same issue.  I would be perfectly happy to have my tasks executed in sequence instead of in parallel.  Is there a way to do this?  Or am I going back to implementing a work queue?

Comment: @Edward Falk: As I wrote above, "Grab the source code, modify it, put it in your own package, and use that one." Just tweak the LinkedBlockingQueue settings to match your desired pattern.

Comment: +1 for Grab the source code, modify it, put it in your own package, and use that one. saved my day!

Comment: Do you considered/added these kind of code? if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
{
  myTask.executeOnExecutor( AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, stuff );
}

Answer (score 7):

I've done this exact same thing myself in an application.

Launching 20 parallel threads at once to download thumbnails from a server and push them to a data adapter doesn't sound like a good idea to me.  All those threads will just trip all over each other and get in each other's way.

Instead, I would launch just one thread, have it collect the thumbnails in a loop, and add them to the adapter as they arrive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the serial executor with AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor, to serialize your tasks, but that will limit the task to only one concurrent task at the time. Might be good though when getting thumbnails:

myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(MyAsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, [params] );

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the number of *pending* AsyncTasks for `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` is 128. Once the queue is filled up no new AsyncTasks can be queued.

From AsyncTask source code:

```
private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);
```

In my opinion that limit makes absolutely no sense at all and `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` has an unlimited queue.

Answer (score 1):

"Safe" to ignore - You need to make sure that any kind of notification that you were planning to do in the post-execute will be done here when you catch the error - otherwise you might leave something hanging if your other code makes assumptions about hearing back from this task.