# AsyncTask in ICS: java.util.concurrent.Rejected Execution Exception

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I got these kind of exception similar to [AsyncTask, RejectedExecutionException and Task Limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492909/asynctask-rejectedexecutionexception-and-task-limit), and "grab code and add to my package".My question is: is this the right anwser, anyone have other official solutions?

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task android.os.**AsyncTask**$3@416cd2e0 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4101be78[Running, pool size = 128, active threads = 128, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 53]

```
    updateTimer.schedule(updateTask, 500, 3000);
```

...

```
    updateTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run()
        {
            updateHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }

    };
```

...

```
    updateHandler = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            updateAsync();
        }

    };
```

...

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            retrieveStatus();
            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            updateStatusUi();// !!!?

        }

    }.execute();
```

---

```
    updateTask = new TimerTask() {

        public void run()
        {
                retrieveStatus();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run()
                    {
                        updateStatusUi();
                    }

                });
        }

    };
```

IN ICS: After about 10 times, it never update any more. Can you please give me a Demo, so I can pass some rigor test like: MainActivity: open(), close(), ...

P.S. myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(MyAsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, [params] ); will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are forking a new thread every 500ms. This is really bad, on any OS, in any programming language.

Second, you are forking yet another thread (your `TimerTask`), that is posting a message back to the main application thread, that is turning around and forking the `AsyncTask`. This is pointless.

If you are going to use a `TimerTask`, simply call `retrieveStatus()` from your `run()` method, then use `runOnUiThread()` to execute `updateStatusUi()` on the main application thread. Now you are only using one background thread (the `TimerTask`) and introducing much less overhead to accomplish the same ends.

Or, consider implementing your own `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of using `TimerTask`.

Comment: "First, you are forking a new thread every 500ms. This is really bad, on any OS, in any programming language." Is this how google suggest to work with AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: @thecr0w: You have linked to the documentation for `AsyncTask`. You will notice that they do not demonstrate starting a new `AsyncTask` every 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Timer got uncautchable exception in ICS while loop my retrieveStatus() and updateStatusUi(), So ScheduledExecutorService is the unique recommended way to do that?

Comment: @thecr0w: You cannot call `updateStatusUi()` from a background thread. That is why, if you read my answer, I suggested that you use `runOnUiThread()` to post a `Runnable` that does the work of `updateStatusUi()`. Beyond that, since I have no real idea what the "uncautchable exception" is, I cannot help you further.

Comment: I did what you say, I put updateStatusUi() in getActivity.runOnUiThread(). I will post code below and this bug really annoy me...