# Which is the right way for multithreading for android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

currently i am using an activity which does asyntask to retrive a list of data from a remote database.

After retrieving under the onPostExecute, i used the method to display out the information gathered from the remote database. Is this the correct way for threading? Previosuly i used a handler in the onPostexecute so that i can intersect the ui thread for displaying information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of ways to achieve multithreading in Android. If you need to perform some background operation then update the UI once this is complete, `AsyncTask`s are definitely the way to go. Keep in mind there is a thread limit. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990948/simple-thread-management-java-android) SO question for more information on thread limits.

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask` is efficient implementation of `Haldler` approach . so whenever multithreading needs to interact with UI thread use AsyncTask else follow standard java threading guidelines.